# Generic lambda cannot be used within a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14, generic-lambda

Consider the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

namespace A {
    template<typename T>
    struct X {
        using Function = std::function<int(T)>;
        static Function f;
    };

    template<typename T>
    typename X<T>::Function X<T>::f = [](auto) { return 42; };

}

int main() {
    std::cout << A::X<int>::f(0);
}
```

Both GCC and clang accept this code but MSVC (tested version 19.00.23506) gives:

`error C2888: 'auto <lambda_ce48e25aa4b9e3d225584044e4eae9e2>::operator ()(_T1) const': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'A'`

And indeed, if I remove namespace A and define everything in the global namespace, the code is accepted. Same if I make lambda expression non-generic.

Can someone explain what is the problem that MSVC sees in this code? Does C++ Standard restrict usage of generic lambdas in contexts like above?

Comment: I would guess if MSVC does not accept that then it is correct code and vice versa

Comment: This is definitely a MSVC bug. Even if the code is invalid, [the error that MSVC gives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2888) doesn't make sense here.

Comment: This is a MSVC bug. There is nothing in the standard that says generic lambdas can only be used in the global namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a MSVC bug but **it has been fixed on VS2017 15.6 preview 2.0**

There is no specification in the standard that restricts generic lambdas to exist only in the global namespace.

POC of the problem can be found here: https://godbolt.org/g/BESMK4

MSVC is not able to deduce that `auto` is exactly `T` in every case, and fails.

In case you need to make it work with MSVC, replace `auto` with explicit `T`:

```
template<typename T>
typename X<T>::Function X<T>::f = [](T) { return 42; };
```

https://godbolt.org/g/cYG9GC

Comment: This is a fine answer. Why would you need to add a comment?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I wanted to add a comment with the workaround instead of a full answer